# Cannot Connect to Postgres db between docker compose services

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, networking, docker-compose

I am trying to connect postgresdb service with nodejs web service using docker compose

My docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
services:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  web:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
      build: ./                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      ports:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
       - "40000:3000"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
      depends_on:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        - postgres
  postgres:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      image: kartoza/postgis:9.6-2.4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      restart: always                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
      volumes:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        - postgresdata:/data/db                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
      environment:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        - POSTGRES_PASS=password                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        - POSTGRES_DBNAME=sticki                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        - POSTGRES_USER=renga                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        - ALLOW_IP_RANGE=0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
      ports:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        - "1000:5432"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
volumes:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  postgresdata:
```

So when i do `docker-compose up` in my root directory both services are running and i can access web service using `localhost:40000` and postgres service using postico on `localhost:1000`

But in Node Web service i have written code to access postgres using Sequelize as

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('sticki', 'renga', 'password', {
  host: 'postgres',
  dialect: 'postgres',
});
```

But I get the following error

```
SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.2:1000
```

Why does postgres Connection is made to 172.18.0.2 instead of localhost(0.0.0.0)?  What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your `web` container `postgres` is a DNS name defined in compose as a service. It fetches the `postgres` DNS IP address via docker internal DNS & network, that's why it's resolving to `172.18.0.2`. If you go to `web` container & `ping postgres`, you will get the same IP.

As a fix, configure your node service to connect to host `postgres` on port `5432` since it's the container port. Port `1000` is the host machine port, if you want to use port 1000, configure node service to connect to your `MACHINE_IP:1000`.

PS - `Localhost` within a container means the container itself & nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Service name is taken from container_name - which is fixed. In your case you do not have that and name is created from folder where docker-compose.yml is + _ + service name + _1. 
With this DNS name you can reach your service on the default network that docker-compose will create, from one service to reach the other.

Thanks